# Is the &= operator a short circuit operator in Java?

Tags: java, boolean, operators

In Java, the `&&` and `||` are short circuit. Thus, they do not evaluate their second operand if not necessary (e.g. `false && a`, `true || b`).

What about the `&=` operator? Is it short circuit as well?

Comment: `&` is not a short circuit operator, so `a = a & b` doesn't short circuit, nor does `a &= b;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not.

There was a thread a while back about why doesn't a `&&=` operator exist. That could've been a short-circuit operator, if it made sense to have it.

Answer (score 2):

No, `&=` is not a boolean operator and as such it does not short-circuit anything, it's a bitwise assignment operator.

It essentially implies assigning first operand with bitwise `&` of first and second operands.

**Quick demo**

```
int i = 01;
int ii = 10;
System.out.println(i &= ii); // assigns i with i & ii and sends i to print stream
i = 01;
ii = 11;
System.out.println(i &= ii);
```

**Output**

```
0
1
```